# Creating content distributions in AWS using CloudFront

Tags: java, amazon-cloudfront

Hi I am trying to create two content distributions in java using cloud front. One for Flash i.e. RTMP and one for HTML5. Where I am stuck is that when I try to make a distribution via Amazon API it gives me the option of creating either of them, how do I do the same in Java?

```
AmazonCloudFrontClient cloudfront = new AmazonCloudFrontClient(credentials);
        CreateCloudFrontOriginAccessIdentityRequest originRequest = new CreateCloudFrontOriginAccessIdentityRequest();
        originRequest.setRequestCredentials(credentials);

        Origin origin = new Origin()
        .withDomainName(bucketName+"s3.amazonaws.com")
        .withId(bucketName)
        .withS3OriginConfig(new S3OriginConfig().withOriginAccessIdentity(""));

        Origins origins = new Origins().withItems(origin);

        DistributionConfig streamingDistributionConfig = new DistributionConfig()
        .withCallerReference("unique-id-for-idempotency")
        .withComment("Streaming CloudFront distribution")
        .withDefaultRootObject("index.html")
        .withEnabled(true)
        .withOrigins(origins); 

        CreateDistributionRequest streamingDistribution = new CreateDistributionRequest()
        .withDistributionConfig(streamingDistributionConfig);           
        cloudfront.createDistribution(streamingDistribution);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well just solved my own question and posting the answer in case someone else needs help

For Streaming Distribution

```
StreamingDistributionConfig streamingDistributionConfig = new StreamingDistributionConfig();
//include the with parameters 
CreateStreamingDistributionRequest streamingDistribution = new CreateStreamingDistributionRequest()
        .withStreamingDistributionConfig(streamingDistributionConfig);          
        cloudfront.createStreamingDistribution(streamingDistribution);
```

For Downloading distribution

```
DistributionConfig downloadingDistributionConfig = new DistributionConfig();
CreateDistributionRequest downloadingDistribution = new CreateDistributionRequest()
        .withDistributionConfig(downloadingDistributionConfig); 
        cloudfront.createDistribution(downloadingDistribution);
```

Enjoy ;)